# Why does Python break the logic of scopes in this example?

Tags: python

Why in the following program does the list redefinition carry to the parent scope of the function? Isn't the point of functions that they have their own "sandboxed" scope?

```py
def dosomething(a):
    a[0] = 10
x = [1, 2, 3]
dosomething(x)
print(x)
```

Expected Output: `[1, 2, 3]`
Actual Output: `[10, 2, 3]`

Shouldn't the code logically have to be the following to produce the actual output?

```py
def dosomething(a):
    a[0] = 10
    return a
x = [1, 2, 3]
x = dosomething(x)
print(x)
```

Comment: You're passing a reference to the list, and then modifying it in place. Scope has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Scope only applies to *variables*.  You have two variables, in different scopes (global `x` and local `a`) that both refer to a single object.

Comment: yes, but in `a[0] = 10` you don't do anything with the variable `a` _itself_ - you merely change the object `a` is referring to.

Comment: Also keep in mind, in case this is the point of confusion, that `a[0] = 10`, despite containing a `=`, is not a normal assignment. That's sugar for `a.__setitem__(0, 10)`. It's just a mutative operation, not an assignment (technically, it's considered to be an assignment syntactically, but it doesn't act like a simple assignment of `a`).

Comment: Neither of the two proposed dupes cover this case. The first simply shows that rebinding a variable name to  a different object within a function has no effect on the original name or object. The second shows the effects of mutability does doesn't really explain *why* it works as it does.

Comment: @paxdiablo This question is being asked every single day in so many words, and these two duplicates are basically the canonical answers. If you understand mutability and pass-by-assignment, the question becomes moot.

Comment: @deceze, I agree with your final sentence whole-heartedly, but I've tend to follow the "question is a dupe (proper subset)" philosophy while others here follow "answered in a question that may be totally different". An answer explaining C undefined behaviour in a question "Does the Java language have strange edge cases?" is unlikely to be found by someone trying to understand C's (many) foibles :-) Of course, you have a blue diamond so are free to override me (and I'll bear no ill will since four other bods in the swarm could do the same), I just thought Id explain why I voted to re-open.

Comment: @paxdiablo, ...for what it's worth, given the longstanding policy that a good answer can salvage a bad question, you may well have salvaged this one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always found it best to think in terms of separating objects from names, where names are bound to objects. This thinking makes understanding Python's behaviour easier in cases such as yours.

For example, the statement `a = [1, 2, 3]` does *two* things:

- it creates the *object* `[1, 2, 3]`; then
- it binds the *name* `a` to that object.

After that, if you do `b = a`, that is *not* creating a new object, it is rather binding `b` to the same object as `a`.

That's why, if you subsequently do `a[0] = 42`, that changes the first element of the *object* that both `a` and `b` are bound to. Meaning that, if you then use `b[0]`, it will be `42`, not `1`.

There is a vast difference between:

- `a[0] = 42` which changes the object that `a` and `b` are bound to; and
- `a = [42, 2, 3]` which creates a *new* object and rebinds `a` to it, leaving the object `b` untouched.

In your case, the `a` is passed into your function and, if you had rebound it to a different object within the function, that change would not survive function exit.

However, you are not rebinding the name, you are changing the object *behind* the name. That object change will persist after the function exits.

Comment: Interesting. Why is this a function of Python? Is it to save resources by avoiding having to create a new copy of that list in memory, or is this a coding standard of logic?